# $\phi : S^n \to S^n$ with no fixed point

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

The question is as follows: "Find a continuous map from $S^1$ to $S^1$ with no fixed points. What about for $n > 1$?"

I want to write $S^n = \{(1, \theta_1, \dots, \theta_n) | 0 \leq \theta_i < 2\pi\}$ and define a continuous map $\phi: (1, \theta_1, \dots, \theta_n) \to (1, \theta_1 + \pi, \dots, \theta_n + \pi)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I thought that was the generalised spherical coordinate form of the boundary of an n-sphere. What does it look like? When does $S^n$ not allow a fixed point free contiuous map? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Strictly speaking all $S^n$ have maps without fixed points.

Comment: What you wrote is the generalization of a torus.

Comment: @user2345215 What would those maps look like?

Comment: Is the map from each point to its antipode ever discontinuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the sphere in the real vector space like this: $S^n=\{v\in\mathbb R^{n+1}:\|v\|=1\}$.

Now just define the map as $\varphi(v)=-v$ for all $v\in S^n$, that's clearly continuous and has no fixed points.